# Need to extract data from html tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping and I am trying to extract the data from html tables and save it as a csv file. How do I do that?

This is what I have done so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
os.chdir('/Users/adityavemuganti/Downloads/Accounts_Monthly_Data-June2018')
soup=BeautifulSoup(open('Prod224_0055_00007464_20170930.html'),"html.parser")
Format=soup.prettify()
table=soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"details"})
```

Here is the html file I am trying to scrape from:

http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/Accounts_Bulk_Data-2019-08-03.zip (It is a zip file). I have uncompressed the zipfile and read the contents into 'soup' as mentioned above. Now I am trying to read the data sitting in the  tag into a csv/xlsx format.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: if it is zip file then you have to download it, uncompressed it and then get data from files.

Comment: Hi furas, I did that. I didn't post the html file as it has my computer's filepath on it.

Comment: It will be better to edit your question and create small, minimal reproducible example of the problem. Expecting that people will download 42MB zip file isn't very realistic.

Comment: Andrej, you're right, I could not think of a better way to post the question at the time. But thanks to Michael's suggestion, I was able to parse it using pandas. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is the way to go here.  [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/io.html#io-read-html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) or if you desire you can also output to xlsx [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html?highlight=to_excel#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel).

```
import pandas as pd

dataframes = pd.read_html('yoururlhere')
# Assuming there is only one table in the file, if not then you may need to do a little more digging
df = dataframes[0]

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response!. I was able to read the html tables I wanted from the file and manipulate them using pandas.

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  Do you mind checking the box to indicate that this was the best answer to your question?  This way when others are searching similar problems, they will see which questions have answers that might be applicable.